I need to add a custom change in erp next locall and pull it to frappecloud
I am new to erp next. I have a website in frappe cloud I need to make some changes in the cloud. eg: In cloud i need to add a field sales person in Pos screen. is it possible? can anyone help me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you no need code for that,
you can just go to relevant form and add field
refer this https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/user/manual/en/custom-field
